# Using java driver for Mongodb, how do you search for multiple values on the same field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm somewhat new to mongo. I want to query on a field for multiple values.
In SQL, I want something like this:

```
select * from table where field in ("foo","bar")
```

Suppose I have the following documents in mongodb

```
{
  "_id":"foo"
}
{
  "_id":"bar"
}
```

I simply want to mimic this query:

```
db.coll.find( { _id: { $in: [ "foo", "bar" ] } } );
```

I want to retrieve all documents whose _id is either "foo" or "bar".
And I'd like to do this using the java driver.

I tried something like

```
BasicDBObject query = new DBObject()
query.append("_id","foo");
query.append("_id","bar");
collection.find(query);
```

But that seems to return only the "bar" document.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the `$in` operator, it may be easier to use `QueryBuilder` to create the query like this:

```java
QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();
qb.put("_id").in(new String[] {"foo", "bar"});
collection.find(qb.get());
```

or a little cleaner:

```java
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("_id").in(new String[] {"foo", "bar"}).get();
collection.find(query);
```

Comment: I also found that I could do it by writing

    new BasicDBObject().put("_id",new BasicDBObject("$in",new String[]{"foo","bar"}))